# Jmeter summary report when using loops

Tags: jmeter

Currently I have a project which does http requests. It pulls the urls from a CSV file using a loop.

This works for me. However when I look at my summary report it gives me the results of only one request (HTTP) rather than the requests for each url in my CSV file. Is there a way to show each url in the summary report when using the loop controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set name of sampler to :

- url-${url_var_csv}

where url_var_csv is the variable name used in CSV Dataset.